# How do I create a rectangular feature in ArcGIS Pro given only 2 coordinates and a width?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I need to create a rectangular feature in ArcGIS Pro that is a representation of a linear tornado path.

I only have the two lat/long coordinates marking the start and points of a line. This straight line is the path the tornado took. I need to 'expand' the line into a rectangle such that this path line and its endpoints are the middle and midpoints of the "short" sides of the tornado path rectangle. I also know the width of the tornado path (how wide the rectangle should be). How do I create an exact rectangle based on this info?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5's editing tools to create the feature in a polygon feature class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using editing tools, this could be done with geoprocessioning tools.

1. Use the [Points to Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm) GP tool to turn the points you created into a line or multiple lines if you have multiple sets, in which case you can use the Line Field with an ID value to indicate which to pair up.
2. Then on the output line file, run a [buffer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) on the line(s) that uses a search distance that is 1/2 the width you want to polygon to be, and set the Line End Type to "FLAT" (note: This optional parameter is not available with a Desktop Basic or Desktop Standard license.) :(

Comment: I did end up following a very similar process (I created a line feature with those endpoints) and then buffered the line. Thanks!